# Can you use includes() within find()?

Tags: javascript

When I try to use `includes()` within `find()` it doesn't come further than 2 items. The JSON file is valid. So I was wondering, is there a better solution since this doesn't seem to work?

```
  async function getTheRightObject(input){
    let Obj = await aJSONFile.find(item => item.AnArray.includes(input));
    console.log(Obj);
    return Obj;
  }

  let userInput = "annother one";

  getTheRightObject(userInput).then(function(output){
    console.log(output);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    //Error things
  });
```

JSON something like:

```
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "Code": "586251af58422732b34344c340ba3",
    "Input": ["official Name", "officialname", "oficial name", "officcial name"],
    "Name": "Official Name",
    "Flavor": "",
    "Image": "https://123.com/image.png"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Code": "597f723dceeca347a243422f9910e",
    "Input": ["another one", "anotherone", "annother one", "another 1"],
    "Name": "Another One",
    "Flavor": "A bit of text",
    "Image": "http://123.com/image2.png"
  },
  etc...
]
```

So I want to search for an object in this JSON file, which matches the users' input with the object `Input` of the JSON file, and sends back the `Name`. But this solution only seems to work for the first 2/3 items or so.

**Edit:**
Well, it seems I only had lower case character in the first 2 objects. In the other objects in the json file I also used upper case characters.

So my solution final is;

1. All `object.Input = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3, 'etc']` in the json file are lower case now
2. use `toLowerCase()` on the input. Like:

`let Obj = await aJSONFile.find(item => item.AnArray.includes(input.toLowerCase));`

This works in my case because I know the objects are quite unique in my case. In any other cases (ie when you expect multiple objects) you can beter use the solution of Tiny Giant or varit05 down here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

find: The **find()** method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

includes: The **includes()** method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

To Answer your question:

Try to use `for` loop with `if` for desired data from an array of object.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks mate for your response. I thought using includes() inside find() was an easy and 'clean' way to do it. Because it worked for the first two items of the json file. 
I'll use a for loop then.

Comment: Glad to know it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which returns a new array containing **all elements** that cause the provided function to return true, whereas [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the value of **the first element** that causes the provided function to return true.

In the example below, I've condensed the JSON, some of the variable names, and removed the irrelevant async/await usage to aid in readability for future readers.

```js
let data = JSON.parse('[{"id":1,"arr":["a","aa","aaa"]},{"id":2,"arr":["b","bb","bbb"]},{"id":3,"arr":["c","cc","ccc"]},{"id":4,"arr":["a","bb","ccc"]}]');

const filter = (field, input) => data.filter(e => e[field].includes(input));

/*
 * For demonstration purposes only.
 * Map the result of the filter call to an array of
 * matching id's, then output a human readable result
 * Example output: "a: [1,4]"
 */
const test = (...args) => (console.log(`${args[1]}: ${JSON.stringify(filter(...args).map(e => e.id))}`), test);

test('arr', 'a')
    ('arr', 'aa')
    ('arr', 'aaa')
    ('arr', 'b')
    ('arr', 'bb')
    ('arr', 'bbb')
    ('arr', 'c')
    ('arr', 'cc')
    ('arr', 'ccc');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% ! important; height: 100% !important }
```